# Send SMS AND copy them into the "sent messages" folder

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, sms

I'm developing an application for windows mobile 6.5. Im writing the code in c#.net and want to send sms due to my app.
I checked out the POOM and sms sending worked fine.

Code:

```
SmsMessage msg = new SmsMessage();

        msg.To.Add(receiver);
        msg.Body = messageText;
        msg.Send();
```

But there's one problem. I want that the messages will be saved/copied to the "send messages" folder, after my program has sent them.
How can I realize that. Is it possible with the POOM, oder should I work with MAPI and generate a converted copy of the msg-Object in the "send messages"-folder?

greets,
raffi

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the message using the SMS account:

```
OutlookSession session = new OutlookSession();
SmsAccount sa = session.SmsAccount;

SmsMessage msg = new SmsMessage();
msg.To.Add(receiver);
msg.Body = messageText;

sa.Send(msg);
```

Comment: At first - thanks for your answer. The sms's will be send, but nevertheless they won't be shown in the sent-messages-folder.